# "(the) most greatest" or "(the) greatest"

Tags: usage, comparative-constructions, superlatives

I'm a beginner so soory for my English. I don't know and couldn't find which one is right on the internet. Is"(the) most greatest" used by people? Or like, is it right to use that? I saw this in a book. Although I say "(the) greatest" normally, just wanted to make sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are right that "the greatest" is correct.

[This article](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/comparative-and-superlative/) explains about comparatives and superlatives. Some adjectives (as the article says, mainly shorter ones) form their comparative and superlative with suffixes (-**er** and -**est**), and some (longer words) use **more** and **most**.

Examples:

> "The most beautiful island in the world."
>
> "The greatest story ever told."

There are a few exceptions (e.g. **good**-**better**-**best**), but using both **most** *and* **-est** together is not correct in standard English.

If you saw "the most greatest" in a book, perhaps it was dialog spoken by a child, or some other example of purposely incorrect language. That is an expression we don't normally use in English.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of expressing this:

> 1. the most *great*
> 2. the *greatest*

Either of the above phrases is possible. *Most great* is not wrong, but the more common, and shorter, is simply *greatest*.

---

Only one thing (or group of things) can be *the* greatest. Combining the two words to say *most greatest* is redundant and, while understandable, would be considered wrong.